# OpenVPN Initialization Sequence Complete with a .ovpn from VPNBook but no Internet connection

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I'm learning with a Kali Linux on a VM and I am not able to connect through any VPN from vpnbook.com. I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bOESrmLH3hM&list=PLYmlEoSHldN7HJapyiQ8kFLUsk_a7EjCw&index=21) tutorials, but I get stuck in the part where it connects through the VPN.

After installing OpenVPN, and starting it with the .ovpn file I get the following:

```
──(root㉿kali)-[~/Downloads/OpenVPN/vpnbook-openvpn-de20]
└─# openvpn vpnbook-de20-udp53.ovpn  
2023-12-01 07:54:13 WARNING: Compression for receiving enabled. Compression has been used in the past to break encryption. Sent packets are not compressed unless "allow-compression yes" is also set.
2023-12-01 07:54:13 DEPRECATED OPTION: --cipher set to 'AES-256-CBC' but missing in --data-ciphers (AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM:CHACHA20-POLY1305). OpenVPN ignores --cipher for cipher negotiations. 
2023-12-01 07:54:13 Note: '--allow-compression' is not set to 'no', disabling data channel offload.
2023-12-01 07:54:13 OpenVPN 2.6.7 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] [DCO]
2023-12-01 07:54:13 library versions: OpenSSL 3.0.11 19 Sep 2023, LZO 2.10
2023-12-01 07:54:13 DCO version: N/A
Enter Auth Username: vpnbook
Enter Auth Password: *******                 
2023-12-01 07:54:20 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
2023-12-01 07:54:20 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]51.75.145.20:53
2023-12-01 07:54:20 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
2023-12-01 07:54:20 UDPv4 link local: (not bound)
2023-12-01 07:54:20 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]51.75.145.20:53
2023-12-01 07:54:20 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]51.75.145.20:53, sid=73db1ef3 01a8d66b
2023-12-01 07:54:20 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
2023-12-01 07:54:21 VERIFY OK: depth=1, CN=vpnbook.com
2023-12-01 07:54:21 VERIFY OK: depth=0, CN=server.vpnbook.com
2023-12-01 07:54:21 Control Channel: TLSv1.3, cipher TLSv1.3 TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, peer certificate: 2048 bits RSA, signature: RSA-SHA256, peer temporary key: 253 bits X25519
2023-12-01 07:54:21 [server.vpnbook.com] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]51.75.145.20:53
2023-12-01 07:54:21 TLS: move_session: dest=TM_ACTIVE src=TM_INITIAL reinit_src=1
2023-12-01 07:54:21 TLS: tls_multi_process: initial untrusted session promoted to trusted
2023-12-01 07:54:21 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1,dhcp-option DNS  213.186.33.99,dhcp-option DNS  91.239.100.100,route 10.8.0.1,topology net30,ping 5,ping-restart 30,ifconfig 10.8.0.26 10.8.0.25,peer-id 2,cipher AES-256-GCM'
2023-12-01 07:54:21 WARNING: You have specified redirect-gateway and redirect-private at the same time (or the same option multiple times). This is not well supported and may lead to unexpected results
2023-12-01 07:54:21 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
2023-12-01 07:54:21 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
2023-12-01 07:54:21 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-option options modified
2023-12-01 07:54:21 net_route_v4_best_gw query: dst 0.0.0.0
2023-12-01 07:54:21 net_route_v4_best_gw result: via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
2023-12-01 07:54:21 ROUTE_GATEWAY 192.168.1.1/255.255.255.0 IFACE=eth0 HWADDR=08:00:27:cb:7e:f5
2023-12-01 07:54:21 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
2023-12-01 07:54:21 net_iface_mtu_set: mtu 1500 for tun0
2023-12-01 07:54:21 net_iface_up: set tun0 up
2023-12-01 07:54:21 net_addr_ptp_v4_add: 10.8.0.26 peer 10.8.0.25 dev tun0
2023-12-01 07:54:21 Data Channel: cipher 'AES-256-GCM', peer-id: 2, compression: 'lzo'
2023-12-01 07:54:21 Timers: ping 5, ping-restart 30
2023-12-01 07:54:23 net_route_v4_add: 51.75.145.20/32 via 192.168.1.1 dev [NULL] table 0 metric -1
2023-12-01 07:54:23 net_route_v4_add: 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.25 dev [NULL] table 0 metric -1
2023-12-01 07:54:23 net_route_v4_add: 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.25 dev [NULL] table 0 metric -1
2023-12-01 07:54:23 net_route_v4_add: 10.8.0.1/32 via 10.8.0.25 dev [NULL] table 0 metric -1
2023-12-01 07:54:23 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

But firefox is not able to load any web page.

The `traceroute 8.8.8.8` (with the vpn up) gives me:

```
┌──(root㉿kali)-[/etc]
└─# traceroute 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.8.0.1 (10.8.0.1)  32.022 ms  31.965 ms  31.913 ms
 2  51.75.145.252 (51.75.145.252)  32.077 ms  32.099 ms  32.106 ms
 3  10.161.42.124 (10.161.42.124)  31.896 ms  31.831 ms  31.770 ms
 4  10.17.242.98 (10.17.242.98)  31.922 ms  31.772 ms 10.17.242.96 (10.17.242.96)  31.588 ms
 5  * 10.73.40.36 (10.73.40.36)  31.418 ms *
 6  * * *
 7  91.121.215.116 (91.121.215.116)  33.100 ms  32.963 ms 94.23.122.246 (94.23.122.246)  32.993 ms
 8  10.200.0.19 (10.200.0.19)  31.426 ms *  31.325 ms
 9  * * *
10  108.170.251.193 (108.170.251.193)  32.662 ms * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8)  30.591 ms  30.569 ms  31.968 ms
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advanced for the patience.

Edit:

My `resolv.conf`

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search Home
nameserver 77.26.11.233
nameserver 212.142.173.65
```

Comment: I suppose that means you get replies when you `ping` a public IP like `8.8.8.8`? What about a domain name like `www.google.com`?

Comment: It doesn't output anything. It stays without every showing nothing.

Comment: What's the content of your `/etc/resolv.conf` and output of `resolvectl`?

Comment: I'll edit the question showing the `resolv.conf`. And the `resolvectl` times out.

Comment: Can you at least ping any of these nameservers?  And does `nslookup www.google.com 77.26.11.233` / `nslookup www.google.com 212.142.173.65` resolve the domain name successfully? Sounds weird that `resolvectl` "times out". Maybe you want to `sudo systemctl disable --now systemd-resolved`.

Comment: Hello. I came back home to answer your comment, started the VM and the VPN. And suddenly it works! I don't know why, but now i can connect. I don't undestand, because it hasn't worked for days, and I've used the same .ovpn file.